# ActionCable only shows data for a bit after reloading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have to reload the page and when I do so, ActionCable only shows the data broadcasted for a bit and then it disappears. I am broadcasting the data when the user logs in and lands on the homepage.

```
  layout 'home'
  before_action :authenticate_user! 

  def index 
    @posts = Post.all 
    NotifChannel.broadcast_to(
      current_user,
      title: 'New things!',
      body: 'All the news fit to print'
    )   
  end 
end
```

Looking up in the rails logs, it looked like the app was sending the data before an upgrade to websocket was established. Not sure though.

Github Repo
https://github.com/killermag/facebook-

Here's what my front-end received function looks like.

```
  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    if (data) {
      console.log("got data")
      let feed = document.querySelector('.feed-right'); 
      feed.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<div> ${data.title} </div>`)  
    } else {
      console.log("didnt get data"); 
    };
```

Comment: Hi Guillermo. Can you describe a bit better what you want to achieve ? Because Actioncable can stream data from back to front. But it is your job to persist the data in HTML. Actioncable is not responsible for "showing" something for a specific amount of time. Are you sure Actioncable is failing here ?

Comment: @Maxence Hey, it looked like the page the user was landing on was also the same page where I was broadcasting from. ie, the same controller action was rendering the view and broadcasting data. when I broadcasted from another controller which didnt render a view, everything was fine. Would there be a workaround this?
As for what I was trying to do, I was trying to send the user their id from the homes controller as soon as they logged in and were redirected to the homepage.

Comment: I don't think it's related. You can broadcast from any controller. The question is : how do you render this view ? Is the broadcasted data saved in database and returned as normal ERB whe you reload the page ? The broadcast usually happens only once and you have to find a strategy to redisplay this data from database when this page is reloaded. I am not too sure if I am clear. But to me there is no obvious problem, it's more about the dsign of your app.